# Issue integrating cypress-angular-unit-test into Cypress plugins

Tags: unit-testing, cypress

I am attempting to add the cypress-angular-unit-test plugin to Cypress.

However, following [the instructions provided on the related GitHub page](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-angular-unit-test) I am getting the following error:

```
 The plugins file is missing or invalid.

 /MyProjectName/cypress/plugins/index.js:1
 import * as cypressTypeScriptPreprocessor from 'cy-ts-preprocessor';
 ^^^^^^

 SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Again, as instructed, I have added the following to support/index.js

```
 // core-js 3.*
 require('core-js/es/reflect');
 // core-js 2.*
 require('core-js/es7/reflect');
 require('cypress-angular-unit-test/support');
```

And the following to plugins/index.js

```
 import * as cypressTypeScriptPreprocessor from 'cy-ts-preprocessor';

 module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('file:preprocessor', cypressTypeScriptPreprocessor);
  require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')(on, config);
  return config;
 };
```

I've also added the related helper.js and cy-ts-preprocessor.js file to the plugins folder.

I've also added the necessary config to cypress.json

```
   "experimentalComponentTesting": true,
```

I've even tried adding types/node by adding a tsconfig.json to the cypress folder like so:

```
 {
  "compilerOptions": {
  "target": "es5",
  "lib": ["es5", "dom"],
  "types": ["cypress", "node"],
  "experimentalDecorators": true
},
 "include": [
 "**/*.ts"
 ]
}
```

Changing the target and/or lib values to es6 has no effect.

Changing the import to a require yields a different error which, even if it did work, seems like a hacky solution for some detail I am missing.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: ^^^^^ guess someone didn't like my shrug emoji ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer but at least a work around.

1. Start fresh or uninstall Cypress and cypress-angular-unit-test
2. Follow the [instructions for Nx Cypress install found on here](https://medium.com/@joaqcid/5-steps-to-set-cypress-as-your-e2e-test-runner-in-angular-bbaf63619a1b)
3. [Go back to cypress-angular-unit-test instructions](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-angular-unit-test) and ignore this part:

---

```
  Configure cypress/plugins/index.js to transpile Angular code.

  import * as cypressTypeScriptPreprocessor from './cy-ts-preprocessor';
   module.exports = (on, config) => { 
   on('file:preprocessor', cypressTypeScriptPreprocessor);
   return config;
  };

  The file cy-ts-preprocessor is here
```